# AppleScript for extracting html message

Tags: applescript

I have created a script with AppleScript to extract email body according to some rules.
`set this_content to (every character of content of this_message) as Unicode text`

But it seems that it extracts body only as a plain text.

Is that possible to get HTML content instead of just plain text? I am getting some tables over mail and would like to parse them, but in case of plain text I see it only as a list of values..

Is it possible to do smth like `set this_content to (every character of content of this_message) as HTML` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to see the HTML (if there is any) in the **source** property of the message, which contains the raw source, e.g.

```
set this_content to source of this_message
```